# Glassfish Server not starting : doSelect IOException Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

i am new to Java EE & glassfish and all that stuff,
for my class I have to create 3 domains and start them.
I have created a domain with asadmin like that :

```
asadmin create-domain --portbase 5000--user admin --savemasterpassword=true middleware
```

But when i add it in Netbeans and start it it says :

```
doSelect IOException
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:125)
```

and so on..

After searching a bit on google I found a few things about the hosts file and tried commenting and uncommenting ::1 localhost but without success.

PS : I'm on win7 64b

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : Proxifier was running and since netbeans looks for ipv6 it wasn't filtered as a localhost rule in proxifier...

I hope it will help ^^